# Python Selenium - pressing javascript src button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on a button that is generated using this javascript code

```
<script type='text/javascript' value name ="clickme" 
src='//examplecode.com/example.js>
```

I'm using driver.findelement and it says "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable", heres my python code:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  # Initializing Chrome Options from the Webdriver
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)  # Adding Argument to Not Use Automation Extension
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])  # Excluding enable-automation Switch

#options.add_argument("disable-popup-blocking")
#options.add_argument("disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--enable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--enable-extensions")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 1}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http://examplesite.com/")

tabName = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "clickme")
tabName.click()


time.sleep(200)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: that's not a button, it's a script.

Comment: i should have clarified more, the script generates a button that can be clicked.

Comment: @TristanFogle it's hard to help without additional info. Could you please explain how the button is generated by script. I assume, you have to perform some action in order to activate the script. Because if the script has been already activated, you'll already be able to find the button. So, what should the real user do on the page, to provoke the button generation? If there is no ability to activate script with some page interaction, so I assume this script contains some function which performs generation. In this way it's possible to call `driver.execute_script('jsFunctionName()')`.

Comment: Basically the script generates an ad, so there isnt any user interaction, its a long script and I dont really understand it, heres the link if that helps any and I really appreciate the help: ```http://pl16974400.trustedcpmrevenue.com/12/79/90/12799002a97e3ad0de8bc5bf28c341fc.js```

Comment: right-click on the button and choose, "Inspect".  That'll give you the info you need to target it.  (Be sure to use a webdriverwait when finding...)

Comment: So if i inspect it, I can use the id to target it right?

Answer (score 0):

maybe have some element layer upper than click() element

try this code:

```
tabname=WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'balabala')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", tabname)
```